# Can we capture the error in batch script when some command shows window errors?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I faced one problem. Am installing some software through batch script. My script file is below

```
msiexec /i "d:\ffr\ff\ff.msi"  /qb /NORESTART  
echo %errorlevel%
```

Here the file d:\ffr\ff\ff.msi not exist in my system so it showing a new window with error message "The installation package could not be opened. Verify that package exists and that you can access it, or contact the application vendor.... "
Then next line echo %errorlevel%  o/p is 0.

we may do this like

```
IF EXIST "d:\ffr\ff\ff.msi" (msiexec /i "d:\ffr\ff\ff.msi"  /qb /NORESTART  )
```

But my need to catch that error message or any information that something went wrong in my batch file. Is there any way ?  Thank you.

Comment: once you click on ok on the new window, it should display errorlevel 1619 on the command line, do you not get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in as a solution, you can only print the error or other text with it purely if `ERRORLEVEL` is bigger than 0

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
ver > nul
msiexec /i "d:\ffr\ff\ff.msi"  /qb /QUIET /NORESTART
if ERRORLEVEL == 1 echo There was a problem with the command error returned %errorlevel%
```

Comment: no all time it showing errorlevel as 0.   like  Errorlevel before executable: 0
Errorlevel after executable: 0
Errorlevel After reset: 0

Comment: that is impossible. did you try the last piece of code?

Comment: I did. `msiexec` does not touch `%errorlevel%` at all. (Win 7 Enterprise, two systems)

Comment: You can use the conditional operators `&&` (previous command successful) and/or `||` (previous command failed), ie `msiexec /i "d:\ffr\ff\ff.msi"  /qb /NORESTART || (echo(Something went wrong & pause & exit/b)`

Comment: I withdraw. Working within a batchfile (with or without `setlocal`). Not working directly on command line. Same with @elzooilogico's suggestion.

Comment: yes it is working.  But in this line of command   if ERRORLEVEL == 1 echo There was a problem with the command error returned %errorlevel%     we can take any number between 1 to 1619 in the place of 1 why this is?

Comment: @SouravGhadai yes you can. will add an edit on how to. If you feel that this helped you, could you kindly mark the answer as correct?

Comment: u just edit and remove first answer that is not working

Comment: Thank You. For your response. @Gerhard Barnard

Comment: Pleasure. let me know if you need any more assistance.